# Diffraction pattern and grating using mesh and Telescope

Tags: diffraction, telescopes

I recently attended a demonstration at an observatory when a undergraduate Astronomy student showed me something neat. A telescope was pointed at a star. The student then waived a window covering with mesh squares of ~35 mm repeats on top of the telescope. This produced a diffraction pattern when looking into the eye piece.

This was really quite surprising to me, but then again I am not a physicist. I am somewhat familiar with Bragg's law and would not have expected this given that wavelength of visible light is at most 750nm or 0.00075mm. So why did we see a diffraction pattern emerge when I looked into the eye piece of the telescope while a mesh with d spacing of ~35mm was on top? To my mind (and obviously I am wrong) this condition would not satisfy Bragg's law.

Be great if someone could explain this.

Best,
Omid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *was* diffraction. You expect the angular size (in radians) of the diffraction pattern features to be of order $\lambda/D$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength and $D$ is the spatial scale of the diffracting element.

Sure, when $\lambda \ll D$ this angular size is small, but you were looking at it through a magnifying eyepiece - maybe $\times 300$?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I get it now. I did not even think about the magnification!

Comment: I am curious how did you calculate 300X magnification? I am off by two orders of magnitude  so I think I am doing something wrong empirically. I doubt the microscope was that good so 300X sounds more correct but I am not sure how you got there.

Comment: @Omid I didn't calculate anything. 300x is a typical magnification for a telescope eyepiece. You have not given us the details of the telescope that was used.